# How to set specific format for E notation in Java

Tags: java, formatting

I need to convert some floats to format like this: `2,5000E-003`, `2,8625E+000`

I know i can do it like this:

```
String.format("%s,%sE%s", digitInt, digitAfterDot, digitDegree)
```

But I hope somebody knows more clever and natty solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
String.format("%1.4e",12345.67890123)
```

The result of this is:

```
1,2346e+04
```

Here is some [documentation](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format)

**EDIT**
If you need 3 digits in the exponent, you can use the `DecimalFormat` Formatter:

```java
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.0000E000");
System.out.print(format.format(12345.67890123f));
```

Which outputs:

```
1,2346E004
```

Note that it does not come with a positive sign if the exponent is positive.
You can fix this with:

```java
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.0000E000");
String result = format.format(12345.67890123f);
if (!result.contains("E-")) {
    result = result.replace("E", "E+");
}
```

Comment: @Flav Thanks a lot, but in my situation it is important to have **three** digits after "e", even if they are equal to zero

Comment: @SergeyYuryev I just edited my answer with another solution